# PHP: Display the first three sentences of a string

Tags: php, regex, string

I'm trying to write a simple function that truncates a string down to its first three sentences. I've written the following and it works well:

```
function getExcerpt($string) {
    if($string != "") {
        $strArray = explode('. ', $string);
        return $strArray[0].'. '.$strArray[1].'. '.$strArray[2].'. ';
    }
    return $string;
}
```

The problem is that it fails when the first few sentences end in "?" or "!".

So, for example, the following text is considered **one** sentence, instead of **three**:

> What is intelligence? How do we define intelligence? This paper seeks to answer that question.

`explode` is no use, so I thought I'd use `preg_split` -- but the problem is that I need to replace the "?"s and "!"s in their right places.

What's a simple way to solve this problem? Is there a handy PHP "sentence" function I don't know about?

Comment: What if someone uses a dot in a sentence? E.g. with abbreviations.

Comment: preg_split('/[.!?]/', $string) will split based on any of those three char's.

Comment: @BartFriederichs That particular issue has never arisen. It's highly unlikely and "E.g. " would be in the first sentence of an essay. Acronyms are also rare in this particular world, but good point! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
$strArray = preg_split('/([.?!]) /', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

That'll give you all three "terminator" characters followed by a space.

Comment: Using regular expressions, however would be much slower than just using `strpos`.

Comment: There is the `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` option, which allows the split chars to be captured into the post-split data: http://php.net/preg_split

Comment: no, because there's a space after the character class. `...[space]` is a single sentence. but if it was `.[space].[space].[space]`, then yes. and a full-blown actual ellipsis char wouldn't match to begin with.

Comment: @MarcB Sorry , I didn't see the space. Unfortunately I have to inform you that the answer is still wrong. `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` requires the regex to be: `/([.?!]) /`. I've edited your answer so it's correct.

Comment: Don't worry about it. It's much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use this regex to directly catch the first three sentences, provided they are ended by one or multiple '.', '?' or '!' :

```
^([^.!?]+[.!?]+){3}
```

It catches every character up to the points and ables to catch multiple points, doing this three times.

Working example : http://regex101.com/r/bT6qG3

Edit : I forgot to mention you don't need to use preg_split in this case. I haven't coded in PHP for a long time but I believe you should use preg_match and that it would be more efficient than with preg_split.

Comment: My pleasure ; it may be PHP related as I do not know much about it. Or maybe the '^' I added at the start of my regex, it is supposed to match the start of the string, maybe you have some sort of prefix?

Answer (score 0):

How about this, using loops and strpos

```
$ArrString = array();
$start = 0;
for ($i=1; $i<=3; $i++) {
    $pos = strpos(str_replace(array('?','!'),'.',$string),'.',$start)+1;
    $ArrString[] = substr($string,$start,$pos-$start);
    $start = $pos;
}
```